# @bindable in typescript not working

Tags: typescript, aurelia

I am using aurelia with TypeScript (v 1.5.4). I am using the typed definitions from `https://github.com/aurelia/<>/blob/master/dist/amd/aurelia-<>.d.ts`. Also I am using VS 2015 for my development with following TypeScript Build configuration:[image: TypeScriptBUildOptions].

However when I am using `@bindable` in my VMs and Views it seems to be not working. Below is an example how I am trying to use in nav-bar:

`nav-bar.ts`:

```
import aur = require("aurelia-framework");
import bindable = aur.bindable;

export class NavBar {
      @bindable router = null;
      ....
}
```

And this is how I am using it in `app.html`:

```
<template>
<import from='./nav-bar'></import>

<nav-bar router.bind="router"></nav-bar>


<div class="page-host row">
    <router-view></router-view>
</div>
</template>
```

But for some reason it doesn't work. Please let me know if I need to do something differently.

Thank You.

Comment: should the `import bindable = aur.bindable;` line say `var bindable = aur.bindable;` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have recently switched to TypeScript but I didn't need to change my @bindable, I did add a type to keep the compiler happy...

```
import { bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';

export class SomeClass{
  @bindable property: boolean = false;
  ...
}
```

Although with my NavBar I did have a problem as I was both binding the router and injecting it, in this case I used an alias for the injected router.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried using `import {} from ''` syntax instead of `require()`, and adding the `Router` type like: `@bindable router:Router = null;`. However unfortunately the binding still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you've set the TypeScript compiler options to enable `experimentalDecorators`. This can be done in the .*proj file if you are using Visual Studio or the tsconfig.json if you are using Gulp / command line.

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "version": "1.5.0",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "declaration": false,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noLib": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "listFiles": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

**.*proj**

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <TypeScriptTarget>ES5</TypeScriptTarget>
    <TypeScriptRemoveComments>false</TypeScriptRemoveComments>
    <TypeScriptSourceMap>true</TypeScriptSourceMap>
    <TypeScriptModuleKind>AMD</TypeScriptModuleKind>
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;DEBUG</DefineConstants>
    <TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>True</TypeScriptCompileOnSaveEnabled>
    <TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>False</TypeScriptNoImplicitAny>
    <TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>true</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators
</PropertyGroup>
```

For more information, see this question:

[Visual Studio 2015 RC Typescript experimental decorators error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896227/visual-studio-2015-rc-typescript-experimental-decorators-error)