# Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2' in VS2013 and typescript 1.6.2

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-2013, typescript1.6

My own project use MVC4. I try to

1. add tsconfig.json "experimentalDecorators": true
2. change project TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators = true and
   TypeScriptEmitDecoratorMetadata = true

and it's not work for me. how to compile typescript and angular2

- I try follow to link :

  1. [Cannot find external module 'angular2/angular2' - Angular2 w/ Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30858164/cannot-find-external-module-angular2-angular2-angular2-w-typescript)
  2. [Visual Studio 2015 RC Typescript experimental decorators error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896227/visual-studio-2015-rc-typescript-experimental-decorators-error)

but not work for me.

Please help me

thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cannot find module 'angular2/angular2'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34697466/cannot-find-module-angular2-angular2)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install typescript definitions:

tsd install -s angular2/angular2

Comment: from the angular2 alpha 44 there is no need to add external typings. typings definitions already added into the angular2 dev directory.

Answer (score 0):

The d.ts files for angular2 are not provided by tsd since 2.0.0-alpha.41. Now they are part of the Distribution and can be found in the toplevel directory.

I'm having comments (**3** slashes) like the following in my files:

`/// <reference path="my/path/angular2@2.0.0-alpha.45/angular2.d.ts" />`

Comment: Could you please elaborate on this? E.g. "(3 slashes) like the following in my files:" - what files you add comments to?