# Using of TypeScript decorators caused errors

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core

I'm using TypeScript in new ASP.NET core project type.

We actively use [decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29775830/how-to-implement-a-typescript-decorator).

Unfortunately, that causes lot of errors in VS2015 output:

```
Error   TS1219  Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release.
Specify '--experimentalDecorators' to remove this warning.  
WebApplication2 d:\documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\WebApplication2\src\WebApplication2\wwwroot\sources\app.ts 9   Active
```

That is quite simple to get rid of these error messages [in regular ASP.NET projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896227/visual-studio-2015-rc-typescript-experimental-decorators-error) modifying `*.csproj` file.

But ASP.NET Core project does not use `.csproj`, it uses `.xproj` instead.

So, how to allow experimental TypeScript decorators support in VS2015 in ASP.NET Core project?

---

You may find simplest project which reproduces the problem [in sample github rep](https://github.com/kaatula/AspNetCore-TypeScript-DecoratorsIssue)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Right click on your project > `Add` > `New Item`.
2. Pick `Client-side` from
   the left hand menu.
3. Add a new `TypeScript JSON Configuration File`. Leave it as the default name of `tsconfig.json`.
4. Open `tsconfig.json`. In the `complierOptions` section, add `"experimentalDecorators": true`.
5. Remove `"wwwroot"` from the `"exclude"` section.
6. Build and enjoy.

Here is my `tsconfig.json` file for completeness:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Right answer! Just a comment on the exclude: You (or the op in this case) aren't supposed to have *.ts files in `wwwroot` folder, as ti's publicly available . The way it was intended is to put all source files in the project root and use gulp or grunt to compile the *.ts files and move the compiled *.js files into wwwroot

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it works fine in VS2015 Update 1 (but does not work without Update 1, that's why we missed this solution :) )

Comment: Hi im getting this error "Unable to get property 'compilerOptions' of undefined or null reference".

Im using latest VS 2015.1 and latest TS plugin for VS.

here is the code ... it's a hello world app nothing more
https://www.dropbox.com/s/2lv2rjdvv1op3an/a1.zip?dl=0