# TypeScript Decorators error in WebStorm

Tags: typescript, webstorm

First - not duplicate of [Using of TypeScript decorators caused errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35460232/using-of-typescript-decorators-caused-errors) since I've used the `"experimentalDecorators" : true` in `tsconfing.json` and it won't help, it's probably a WebStorm issue.

So I use Mobx and try to use it's decorators and I get this error (which is straight forward):

[image]

Thing is, my tsconfig on the root of the project already have this, here is my tsconfig file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "target": "es5",
    "jsx": "react",
    "lib": ["dom", "es2016"],
    "types": ["mocha", "chai", "node", "protractor"]
  },
  "include": [
    "./test/matchers/custom.matchers.d.ts",
    "./test/**/*.ts"
  ],
  "files": [
    "./src/external-types.d.ts",
    "./src/app.tsx"
  ]
}
```

What am I missing? Why WebStorm keep showing this error on every decorator?

Comment: Is your form-store.ts file under the `./test/` directory? Is it even valid to use both files and include in the tsconfig.json? The documentation seems to imply that it's one or the other: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html

Comment: @JBNizet it's not under the test directory, in general everything else works just fine, it's only the decorators that makes an issue

Comment: Then your tsconfig.json doesn't apply to this file, since it's not included.

Comment: @JBNizet you are right... I missed it, please post an answer so I can accept and upvote :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tsconfig.json doesn't apply to this file, since it's not under `./test`, and your tsconfig.json has

```
"include": [
  "./test/matchers/custom.matchers.d.ts",
  "./test/**/*.ts"
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need the parenthesis, it is not `@observable`, it is `@observable()`, same goes for the other one