# Visual studio Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release error

Tags: angular, typescript

I have common-helper.ts in my angular 6 app and i take "Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option to remove this warning". **Is my naming convention is wrong?** Because when i remove "-" and change to file name to "commonhelper.ts" the error is fixing. And when i add tsconfig.json file "experimentalDecorators": true, error isn't fixing.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class CommonHelper {

  constructor() { }

  }
}
```

my tsconfig.json file

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    //"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2017",
      "dom"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: No, there is nothing wrong with your code. It's just typescript telling you exactly that, decorators might change their implementation at a later point. Go to tsconfig and add `"experimentalDecorators": true` to your compiler options

Comment: I changed it from tsconfig.json. But it is not fix. @ritaj

Comment: Try recompiling your project and turn off/on your text editor.

Comment: I recompiled project and turn off/on text editor. But still give me error. I edited my question and i added my tsconfig.json to question @ritaj

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In **tsconfig.json**:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowJs": true,
...
}
```

Which is what every other comment/post I've scoured the internet on the subject says... and kept me frustrated... but I figured out what made the difference is:

***PUT THIS AT THE VERY TOP OF COMPILER OPTIONS BEFORE ANYTHING ELSE***

So something is messing it up due to ordering.  Hope that helps?  Put the experimentalDecorators and allowJS parameters at the very top of your object before anything else.

Comment: This didn't work for me, for the time being it seems ok, so whether I stay in VSC or close and open back my angular 7 project, it still gives the red squiggly line and shows for e.g. if I have opened up app.component.ts then it shows as   Experimental support for decorators is a feature that is subject to change in a future release. Set the 'experimentalDecorators' option in your 'tsconfig' or 'jsconfig' to remove this warning.

Comment: In VSCode go to `preferences -> settings`, you will see an option to `enable/disable experimentalDecorators`. Check it and save the settings file. Done

Answer (score 12):

This [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30896227/visual-studio-2015-rc-typescript-experimental-decorators-error) worked for me.

Modify your .csproj file to add:
`<TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>True</TypeScriptExperimentalDecorators>`

Comment: So you are saying this is a duplicate answer/question perhaps

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem in my Ionic app. Simply I had opened only the src folder from Visual Studio. You will sort the problem if you open the whole ionic folder with Visual Studio, form me the error disappeared. Point at the main folder with Visual Studio and from there navigate to ionic home.page.ts files ecc.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For junior developers this become frustrating.
Sometimes this problem can be because of the file extension interchange between `.js` and `.ts`.
So kindly take a second look at your JavaScript file extension and make sure it is `.ts` where it applies. Thank you.